# php mysql Maximum execution time of 300 seconds exceeded_fatal error

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I am querying data from a database, and the query clause varies with the day.
In other words, I want to get data in one-day unit by counting seconds in unix timestamps.

So, what I did for one-day-query is,

```
SELECT IDnum, Timestamp FROM table_name
WHERE CONVERT(Timestamp, UNSIGNED INTEGER) >= ($start_tim-86400*($i+1))
  AND CONVERT(Timestamp, UNSIGNED INTEGER) < ($start_time-86400*$i)
```

because Timestamp attribute in table is varchar(32), I used CONVERT() in where clause to convert it to int, and compare with int type of 86400.

This query clause works so far, but it takes at least 5 mins in that I set ini_set('max_execution_time', 300). And after 5 mins, it showed 
"Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 420 seconds exceeded in C:\www\LineChartOne\generateJSONdata.php on line 90", and still not complete.

My question is why it need so much time and, because I used function call in the "where clause"? Or something wrong with the "where clause", otherwise it should not run so slowly.

Comment: Consider having MySQL explain what's going on: DESCRIBE SELECT IDnum, Timestamp FROM table_name WHERE CONVERT(Timestamp, UNSIGNED INTEGER) >= ($start_tim-86400*($i+1)) AND CONVERT(Timestamp, UNSIGNED INTEGER) < ($start_time-86400*$i) ^^^^^^^^ That should shed some light on what's taking so much time.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that the `CONVERT()` is super inefficient. Use `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()` or `FROM_UNIXTIME()` or [date functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html) like `DATE_SUB()` or `DATE_DIFF()` to compare the dates.

If it *still* takes forever then either there's something wrong and you don't have tens of millions of rows then it is likely that:

1. Your PHP code is inefficient.
2. There's more to this query than what you're showing.
3. Your web and or mySQL servers are under heavy load from other users.

### Edit:

Sweet jesus, the code in your comment makes my brain itch. Also I just now realized that your `Timestamp` column is a VARCHAR and not a TIMESTAMP. *Bad user*. Do not store numbers or dates as strings. Go sit in the corner.

- Option 1: Make it an INT. [works with your existing code]
- Option 2: Make it a DATETIME. [generally more flexible]

Things your are not getting:

1. `FROM_UNIXTIME()` converts an integer timestamp to a `DATETIME` type. If you feed it a string it will do an implicit conversion. [conversions are *slow*]
2. `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()` takes a date string, `DATE`, or `DATETIME` and returns an integer.

The code you gave `UNIX_TIMESTAMP(FROM_UNIXTIME(Timestamp))` converts the string to an int to a date back to an int. [The documentation is here, read up on it.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html)

The vast majority of the reason why your query takes so long is because mySQL has to convert all of the values in `Timestamp` from `VARCHAR` to `INTEGER`. Change the column type and you can do simple integer comparisons which will be *worlds* faster.

A much smaller performance gain can be had by pre-computing the expression `$start_time-86400*($i+1)` in PHP. mySQL *should* optimize to evaluate only once, but the optimizer can do funky things when your queries become more complex and it might start computing this for each row.

Comment: Thanks for your help.
I changed to:
"SELECT IDnum, Timestamp, A, B, FROM krisdata WHERE UNIX_TIMESTAMP(FROM_UNIXTIME(Timestamp)) >= (($start-$incompleteDay)-86400*$i) AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP(FROM_UNIXTIME(Timestamp)) <= $start AND A > 0.0 AND B > 0.0";
It still takes forever.

Based on your 3 assumptions:

Comment: Based on your 3 assumptions:
1. my php code dies at Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 300 seconds exceeded in C:\www\LineChartOne\generateJSONdata.php on line 107. 
Line 107 is $results = mysql_query($sqlQuery) so it is still query clause takes much time?
2. All my query condition is posted here, only reply with A B these two short names and about A B they must be greater than 0
I do not know what to do next, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

The mysql query parser is struggling with converting those columns, you need to use the correct data types for the values you are storing, ie: int for int, varchar for strings,  datetime etc....

Answer (score 0):

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', 300); //300 seconds = 5 minutes
```

Place this at the top of your PHP script and let your script loose!

Taken from [Increase PHP Script Execution Time Limit Using ini_set()](http://davidwalsh.name/increase-php-script-execution-time-limit-ini_set)